# Getting the value of an HTML Element

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have this piece of code here, that's supposed to find an HTML element on [this Reddit page](https://old.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/75ow3h/the_changing_american_household_oc/) and then return a value from it, and then store that in a zero-based 1d array. (I have an internet explorer instance called IE)

```
Dim awardelements As Object
Dim awards As String

    awardelements = IE.document.querySelector("#siteTable > div")(0)
    awards = awardelements.getAttribute("data-gildings")
    results(i + 1, 14) = awards
```

So I'm trying to get the value of "data-gildings" (the # of awards the post got), but I'm getting an automation error on the `awardelements = IE.document.querySelector("#siteTable > div")(0)` line. I'm not sure I can use the JS querySelector like that tbh so that might be the problem. I'd appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction!

Thanks ^^

Comment: You need to use `Set` when assigning an object-type variable

Comment: Fixed that, thanks! But I'm still getting an "Automation Error" on that same line, so I'm still stuck unfortunately

Comment: You should use the MSHTML COM interfaces rather than using `Object` so you can have type-safety.

Comment: I'm afraid that's way beyong my level @Dai :( I've just begun learning VBA unfortunately!

Comment: Do `Dim doc As IElementSelector : Set doc = IE.document: Dim result As IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection : Set result = doc.querySelector( "#siteTable > div" )` and then inspect `result` in your debugger without using the `(0)` indexer, just to make sure that the problem isn't your selector syntax or to determine if the seelctor returned zero elements.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a bit confused about the formatting of that, is that supposed to be all in one line? Also I'm not sure how to inspect anything, which is why I said I was out of my depth a bit :/

Comment: querySelector returns a single node not a collection so declare as object is safest way unless certain of return type.

Comment: @QHarr Whoops! Sorry - I got `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` mixed-up. Unfortunately StackOverflow now doesn't let you edit comments older than 5 minutes (which is dumb...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`querySelector` returns a single node not a collection you can index into. And you need Set keyword as mentioned.

```
Dim awards As Object, awardCount As String

Set awards = ie.document.querySelector("#siteTable > div")
awardCount = awards.getAttribute("data-gildings")
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I didn't realize I was using querySelector and not querySelectorAll.
That works! Thanks again :)